# Document font ignored when using \let

Tags: fonts, macros

I'm using `fourier-otf` and XeLaTeX and noticed something weird. This is my MWE.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier-otf}

\let\eps\varepsilon
\def\epsd{\varepsilon}

\begin{document}
    $ \varepsilon $ %

    $ \eps $        % \let

    $ \epsd $       % \def'ined
\end{document}
```

And the result is the following.

[image]

When I use `\let` to define the new command, the document font is ignored and the epsilon is typeset in default Computer Modern. With `\def` it works fine.

I've always used `\let` when I wanted to define an alias, because I think that `\let\eps\varepsilon` "copies" the definition of `\varepsilon` into `\eps`. And it seems to be true, as both `\show` the same definition: `\mathchar"122`.

What I can't understand is why these two...

```tex
\eps=\mathchar"122
\varepsilon=\mathchar"122
```

... behaves differently, while `\epsd=\varepsilon` works.

---

I tested it with some other `-otf` fonts (`libertinus-otf` and `dejavu-otf`) and it shows the same behaviour. However, `fourier` (probably a ttf version) works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would `\let` and `\def` give different results? It's because the meaning of `\varepsilon` changes between the time that you did `\let\eps\varepsilon` and when you actually used `\eps`.

You can see the change of meaning by adding `\typeout{\meaning\varepsilon}` before and after `\begin{document}` where you will see the initial meaning:

```
\mathchar"122
```

and the meaning once you're in the document:

```
macro:->\mitvarepsilon
```

So when you did the `\let` you told LaTeX you wanted `\eps` to have the meaning *at the time of the `\let`* which was `\mathchar"122`. When you did the `\def` you told it to use the meaning of `\varepsilon` *at the time that you used the new command*.

As for how/why this happens, it's because the `unicode-math` package, which is used by `fournier-otf`, pushes the definition of various symbols to occur during `\begin{document}` to avoid being stomped on by other packages which might be loaded by the user. `fournier`, which doesn't use `unicode-math`, doesn't have this protection.

All that said, the preferred way to create your command would be with

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
```

rather than `\let`. The primary use of `\let` is to grab the meaning of a command at that moment and regardless of what is happening with package loading and the timing of command declarations, that is not what you actually want.

Comment: It makes all sense. Thank you!