# newwrite out of a table with umlauts

Tags: pgfplotstable, write

I have a follow-up question on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598981/46023

Everything works in the MWE there, but when used in my original example it no longer works (note: originaltable.csv is a greatly shortened version of the original, what comparisons, calculations, etc. are made of).

The umlaut 'ä' in the word 'Molybdän', as written in originaltable.csv, is the problem.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{originaltable.csv}
Z; Symbol; Name
2; He; Helium
41; Mo; Molybdän
\end{filecontents}
    
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=true]{originaltable.csv} {\psetable}

% Methode % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598981/46023
\makeatletter
\long\def\protected@iwrite#1#2#3{\begingroup%
#2%
\let\protect\@unexpandable@protect%
\edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#3}}%
\reserved@a%
\endgroup%
\if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi}
\newcommand{\mywrite}[2]{\protected@iwrite#1{}{#2}}%
\makeatother
   
\begin{document}
\newwrite\out
\immediate\openout\out=out.csv

\foreach[count=\n from 0] \row in {0,1}{%%
% In:
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Z}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\Z{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Symbol}\of{\psetable}%
\xdef\Symbol{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Name}\of{\psetable}%
\xdef\Name{\pgfplotsretval}%
% Out:
\mywrite\out{\Z; \Symbol; \Name}% does not work :(
}%%
\immediate\closeout\out

%\input{out.csv}
% Target in: 
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=false]{out.csv}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have used `\xdef` (again not a latex command so already broken all accent commands before you get to the write.

Comment: I think `newrite` in your title is meant to be `newwrite`.  (I can't submit an edit for just one character.)

Comment: I don't konow what's the point with def, xdef, let etc.; but I foccused it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599122/read-out-and-edit-data-from-a-table-with-def-edef-let-etc-by-using-a-pgf-l

Answer (score 6):

The problem is how pdfLaTeX deals with ä (and other accented characters). The fast and simple solution: Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Where you're running into trouble is when you do `\xdef` on `\pgfplotsretval`. You bypass any expansion protection that might have been available. The simplest workaround for this is to *not* use `\xdef` but instead to use `\let`. I talked a bit about `\let` vs defining a macro at this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598902/202780 yesterday. This is one of those cases where `\let` is exactly the right tool for the job.

If you had wanted to do `\edef`, the options provided by LaTeX require going outside the realm of user-level commands with either the private command, `\protected@edef` or the expl3 equivalent, which escapes me at the moment and I can't find in my cursory look through interface3.pdf but I'm sure David Carlisle will jump in and supply it even though in this case `\let` is the best solution.

Comment: There is no expl3 variant of protected@edef,  the whole idea of protection and the various meaning of \protect is a LaTeX concept and don't belong into the expl3 programming layer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That would be why I couldn't find it. I do have a vague notion of David pointing me at something else beyond the `\protected@*def` commands but I couldn't find his comment nor what he talked about (I also checked `xparse` in case that was what I should have been looking for). ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for using `\xdef` (which would break accented characters).

Since the write operation happens inside the loop cycle and it's `\immediate`, there's no need for global definitions either. You just need to save `\pgfplotsretval` under a different (local) name.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-original.csv}
Z; Symbol; Name
2; He; Helium
41; Mo; Molybdän
\end{filecontents}
    
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=true]{\jobname-original.csv} {\psetable}

% Methode % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598981/46023
\makeatletter
\providecommand\protected@iwrite[3]{%
  \begingroup
  #2%
  \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#3}}%
  \reserved@a
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
\newcommand{\mywrite}[2]{\protected@iwrite#1{}{#2}}%
\makeatother
   
\begin{document}
\newwrite\out
\immediate\openout\out=\jobname.csv

\foreach[count=\n from 0] \row in {0,1}{%%
  % In:
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Z}\of{\psetable}%
  \let\Z\pgfplotsretval
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Symbol}\of{\psetable}%
  \let\Symbol\pgfplotsretval
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Name}\of{\psetable}%
  \let\Name\pgfplotsretval
  % Out:
  \mywrite\out{\Z; \Symbol; \Name}% works!
}
\immediate\closeout\out

%\input{out.csv}
% Target in: 
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=false]{\jobname.csv}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

(File names changed to avoid clobbering my files.)

The contents of the written file is

```
2; He; Helium
41; Mo; Molybdän
```

as expected.

An `expl3` version.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-original.csv}
Z; Symbol; Name
2; He; Helium
41; Mo; Molybdän
\end{filecontents}
    
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=true]{\jobname-original.csv} {\psetable}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\startwritingfile}{mm}
 {% #1 = output stream, #2 = file name
  \iow_new:N #1
  \iow_open:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\finishwritingfile}{m}
 {% #1 = output stream
  \iow_close:N #1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mywrite}{mm}
 {% #1 = output stream, #2 = tokens to write
  \iow_now:Nx #1 { \text_expand:n { #2 } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\startwritingfile{\out}{\jobname.csv}

\foreach[count=\n from 0] \row in {0,1}{%%
  % In:
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Z}\of{\psetable}%
  \let\Z\pgfplotsretval
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Symbol}\of{\psetable}%
  \let\Symbol\pgfplotsretval
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Name}\of{\psetable}%
  \let\Name\pgfplotsretval
  % Out:
  \mywrite\out{\Z; \Symbol; \Name}% works!
}
\finishwritingfile{\out}

%\input{out.csv}
% Target in: 
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=false]{\jobname.csv}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in some comments:
`LuaLaTeX` let it work without any special method.

[image]

```
% arara: lualatex

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{originaltable.csv}
Z; Symbol; Name
2; He; Helium
41; Mo; Molybdän
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=true]{originaltable.csv} {\psetable}
\begin{document}
\newwrite\out
\immediate\openout\out=out.csv

\foreach[count=\n from 0] \row in {0,1}{%%
% In:
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Z}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\Z{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Symbol}\of{\psetable}%
\xdef\Symbol{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Name}\of{\psetable}%
\xdef\Name{\pgfplotsretval}%
% Out:
\immediate\write\out{\Z; \Symbol; \Name}% does not work :(
}%%
\immediate\closeout\out

%\input{out.csv}
% Target out: 
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=false]{out.csv}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```